# JSONP print all data

Tags: javascript, ajax, loops, jsonp

So I have a problem with JSONP. I finally managed to load my JSONP data into my html file, but I can't seem to print all the data. I already tried the for loop and $.each, but no succes.

JSONP in php file

```
<?php echo $_GET["callback"] ?> (
{
"expo":"pit",
"datum":"05.06.2011 - 05.06.2016",
"img":"images/pit_home.jpg",
"link":"indexpit.html"
},
{
"expo":"Space Odessy 2.0",
"datum":"17.02 - 19.05.2013",
"img":"images/so_home.jpg",
"link":"indexso.html"
}
);
```

Script for calling the JSONP

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.ajax({
type: 'GET',
jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
contentType: 'application/json',
dataType: 'jsonp',
url: 'http://mllsdemode.be/Ex-cache/home.php',
success: function(json) {
            for (var key in json) {
                var el = document.getElementById("home");
                el.innerHTML = "<li><a href=" + json.link + " data-ajax='false'><img src=" + json.img + "><div class='dsc'>" + json.expo + "<br><em>" + json.datum + "</em></div></a></li>";
            }
         },
error: function() { alert("Error reading jsonP file"); }
});
</script>
```

Anyone know what I should do to print all the info? At this moment I only get the data for pit, not the data for Space Odessy 2.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
The JSONP should be:

<?php echo $_GET["callback"] ?> (
    [
        {
        "expo":"pit",
        "datum":"05.06.2011 - 05.06.2016",
        "img":"images/pit_home.jpg",
        "link":"indexpit.html"
        },
        {
        "expo":"Space Odessy 2.0",
        "datum":"17.02 - 19.05.2013",
        "img":"images/so_home.jpg",
        "link":"indexso.html"
        }
    ]
);
```

You were missing the `[]` around the array, so you were passing two arguments to the callback function instead of one array.

After that, your loop is wrong. It's processing a single object, not an array, and replacing the `home` inner HTML each time instead of appending.

```
success: function(json) {
    var $home = $("#home");
    $home.empty();
    $.each(json, function(i, el) {
        $home.append("<li><a href=" + el.link + " data-ajax='false'><img src=" + el.img + "><div class='dsc'>" + el.expo + "<br><em>" + el.datum + "</em></div></a></li>");
    });
 }
```

Comment: I tried this, but it doesn't print any of the data. Very strange!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php echo $_GET["callback"] ?> ([
{
    "expo":"pit",
    "datum":"05.06.2011 - 05.06.2016",
    "img":"images/pit_home.jpg",
    "link":"indexpit.html"
},
{
    "expo":"Space Odessy 2.0",
    "datum":"17.02 - 19.05.2013",
    "img":"images/so_home.jpg",
    "link":"indexso.html"
}]);
```

.

```
$(json).each(function (index, item) {
    var el = document.getElementById("home");
    el.innerHTML += ("<li><a href=" + item.link + " data-ajax='false'><img src=" + item.img + "><div class='dsc'>" + item.expo + "<br><em>" + item.datum + "</em></div></a></li>");
});
```

Comment: I also tried this solution, but I also get no results with this. It doesn't print any of the data.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
json = $.parseJSON(json);
```

now you can loop through it like following :

```
for(i=0; i<json.length; i++)
{
   alert(json[i].expo);
}
```

Your Array must be in this format [{},{}];

Thanks